# I cannot access radio button with selenium webdriver in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

I cannot access the radio button with chrom websriver in selnium.
I am writing my code in c#
here is the code I am using

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name=eventCategoryID]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value=11]")).Click();
```

for this radio button

Comment: Well what happens? What errors?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some quotation marks. It should look like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[name=\"eventCategoryID\"]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value=\"11\"]")).Click();
```

The \ escapes the following quotation mark so that it doesn't end the string.

Comment: Or you can just use single quotes instead so you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: Use a tool like Firepath to test your css selectors before you use them

Comment: I find that easiest is to use verbatim strings in C#. So you would use::: driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(@"input[value=11]")).Click(); ::: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, those are viable alternatives. I am probably just a bit old fashioned in escaping characters like that.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try XPath

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("")).Click();
```